# Issue in running Spring MVC through Java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was trying to run the spring web mvc application through java config. I was getting the 404 exception. Why it is not running? I put my code below.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>spring-jpa-tutorial-one</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        net.petrikainulainen.spring.datajpa.config.ApplicationContext
    </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

ApplicationContext

```
package net.petrikainulainen.spring.datajpa.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

import com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "net.petrikainulainen.spring.datajpa.controller" })
@EnableWebMvc
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ApplicationContext {

    private static final String VIEW_RESOLVER_PREFIX = "/WEB-INF/jsp/";
    private static final String VIEW_RESOLVER_SUFFIX = ".jsp";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY = "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_MESSAGESOURCE_BASENAME = "message.source.basename";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_MESSAGESOURCE_USE_CODE_AS_DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "message.source.use.code.as.default.message";

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BoneCPDataSource dataSource = new BoneCPDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment
                .getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager()
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean()
                .getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean()
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean
                .setPackagesToScan(environment
                        .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        entityManagerFactoryBean
                .setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL,
                environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY, environment
                .getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL,
                environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_MESSAGESOURCE_BASENAME));
        messageSource
                .setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(Boolean.parseBoolean(environment
                        .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_MESSAGESOURCE_USE_CODE_AS_DEFAULT_MESSAGE)));
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix(VIEW_RESOLVER_PREFIX);
        viewResolver.setSuffix(VIEW_RESOLVER_SUFFIX);
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

DataJPAExampleInitializer

```
package net.petrikainulainen.spring.datajpa.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

/**
 * Web application Java configuration class. The usage of web application
 * initializer requires Spring Framework 3.1 and Servlet 3.0.
 * 
 * @author Petri Kainulainen
 */
public class DataJPAExampleInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";
    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING = "/";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(ApplicationContext.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }
}
```

HomeController

```
package net.petrikainulainen.spring.datajpa.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    protected static final String HOME_VIEW = "home";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showPage() {
        return HOME_VIEW;
    }
}
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title><spring:message code="spring.data.jpa.example.title" /></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <spring:message code="spring.data.jpa.example.homepage.title" />
    </h1>
    <p>
        <spring:message code="spring.data.jpa.example.welcome.message" />
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
           xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">
        <!--
            Configures the location of static resources such as css files.
            Requires Spring Framework 3.0 or higher.
        -->
        <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"/>

    <!--
        Ensures that dispatcher servlet can be mapped to '/' and static resources
        are still served by the containers default servlet. Requires Spring Framework
        3.0 or higher.
    -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <!--
        Configures Spring Data JPA and sets the base package of my DAOs.
    -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="net.petrikainulainen.spring.datajpa.repository"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: please provide some stack trace.

Comment: What is the url that you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "net.petrikainulainen.spring.datajpa.controller" })
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("net.petrikainulainen.spring.datajpa.repository")
public class ApplicationContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String VIEW_RESOLVER_PREFIX = "/WEB-INF/jsp/";
    private static final String VIEW_RESOLVER_SUFFIX = ".jsp";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY = "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_MESSAGESOURCE_BASENAME = "message.source.basename";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_MESSAGESOURCE_USE_CODE_AS_DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "message.source.use.code.as.default.message";

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BoneCPDataSource dataSource = new BoneCPDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment
                .getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager()
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean()
                .getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean()
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean
                .setPackagesToScan(environment
                        .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        entityManagerFactoryBean
                .setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL,
                environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY, environment
                .getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL,
                environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename(environment
                .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_MESSAGESOURCE_BASENAME));
        messageSource
                .setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(Boolean.parseBoolean(environment
                        .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_MESSAGESOURCE_USE_CODE_AS_DEFAULT_MESSAGE)));
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix(VIEW_RESOLVER_PREFIX);
        viewResolver.setSuffix(VIEW_RESOLVER_SUFFIX);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not working, I tried this url http://localhost:8080/spring-jpa-tutorial-one/. I didnt get any exceptions.